# Is there a way to get a HEAD~<number> by commit hash sum in git

Tags: git

I have a particullar commit hash. Is there a way to get the "number" of the HEAD for this commit?

Comment: I'm stuggling to think of a scenario where `HEAD~n` is more useful that the commit id. Is there a bigger problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

If you temporarily tag your `HEAD` then you can use `git describe --contains` to get this information.

```
# make a temporary tag because describe will only use tags
git tag tmpXYZ

git describe --contains --match tmpXYZ <commit-id>
# prints something like tmpXYZ~21, or perhaps something more complex

# remove temp tag
git tag -d tmpXYZ
```

Note that if the commit that you are looking at is not on a direct, first-parent path from `HEAD` you may get a more complex description such as (real example): `tmpXYZ~64^2~14^2~1`.